# Inserting strings to a table in a loop

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Hi I'm trying to create tables in sqlite via sqlite3 in python3.
The code I got so far is:

```
import sqlite3
text="hello"
db = sqlite3.connect('C:/DB.db')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (sida)" % name)
for i in range(10):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s)" % (name, str(text))) # This does not work
db.commit()
db.close()
c.close
```

Changing the value from str(text) to i works;

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s)" % (name, i))         # This works
```

Passing an integer as the value works but not a string. I've been trying to find a solution but I'm stuck.

The error I get is:

> c.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s)" % (name, str(text)))
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: near "a2": syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a prepared statement for your inserts, binding values to any placeholders which exist:

```
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (sida)" % name)
for i in range(10):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (?)" % name, (str(text),))
db.commit()
db.close()
c.close
```

Actually, it would also be better to not make the table name itself dynamic.

Comment: Wow that was quick! Thank you Tim! I'll accept your answer when the timeout has passed

Comment: Just for the record, the exact mode of failure in your query/code is that you have an unquoted string in the `VALUES` clause.  You _could_ fix it by just putting single quotes around `name`, but using a prepared statement is a much better fix.

Comment: I'll sneak in another question if you dont mind:

c.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (sida)" % str(name)

Doesn't accept if name consist of "/" or ":" or similar characters. Is there a way to allow this?

Comment: Yes, put the table name in double quotes, e.g. `CREATE TABLE "blah/stuff"`.  But, I _don't_ recommend using special characters in your table or column names, because you will forever have to escape them in double quotes.

Comment: Oh allright, the name of the table is dynamic as well (I left that part out in the original question). I'll poke around and see If I find something that fits my needs. Thanks again!